# Mailscanner increase spam score by domain

Tags: mailscanner

Our email server is getting lots of spam that isn't in our local language or is translated with help of Google. Our business 99% is local within country.
Is it possible in Mailscanner to increase spam score (by N points) if email is coming from  `.cn` domain?

Basically I want to increase spam score if email is from Asia domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out solution. Question is a little bit inaccurate ... but that I figured out after research. The correct solution is `spamassassin`

```
header FROM_DOMAIN_RU From:addr =~ /\.ru/i
describe FROM_DOMAIN_RU mail from ru domain
score FROM_DOMAIN_RU 3
```

Currently I am testing this.

--== Edit ==--
This is working :)

Comment: Whoa, you had been banned `.ru` before it became mainstream :-)